# Проблема с закачкой торрентов

Tags: python

Закачка начинается, скорость растет. Но через секунд 10-15 количество пиров резко падает на 0. в чем может быть проблема?

---

```
import libtorrent as t
import time

session = t.session()
session.listen_on(6868,6891)
info=t.torrent_info("torrents/nebo.torrent")
h = session.add_torrent({'ti': info, 'save_path': './'})
while (not h.is_seed()):
    time.sleep(1)
    s = h.status()
    state_str = ['queued', 'checking', 'downloading metadata',\
                 'downloading', 'finished', 'seeding', 'allocating']
    print '%.2f%% complete (down: %.1f kb/s up: %.1f kB/s peers: %d) %s' %\
          (s.progress * 100, s.download_rate / 1000, s.upload_rate / 1000,\
           s.num_peers, state_str[s.state])
```

Comment: Возможно трекеры блокируют некоторые торрент-клиенты? Как можно изменить user-agent`a у libtorrent`a скажем на uTorrent?

Comment: Если Вы уже получили пиров — значит трекер тут точно не при чем. К сожалению, с потрохами Deluge/libtorrent знаком слабо, так что сказать в чем дело не возьмусь. Попробуйте найти как получить список peer'ов и посмотреть на него, возможно все вас блокируют (choke) по какой-то причине?